# WCF Tracing (svclog) getting stopped intermittently. Starts after recycling AppPool

Tags: wcf, trace

I have enabled WCF tracing in my service by adding the standard settings in web.config(see below) and it works perfectly fine. The svclog file is getting generated. However after some hours, it just stops capturing logs (i.e the svclog file is not updated). Please note that the service is working fine all this time. Only the svclog file does not get updated.

Once I recycle the appPool, it starts working and the svclog starts getting updated again.

Could there be issues in my WCF service ? If yes how is this related to "tracing getting stopped"

```
    <system.diagnostics>
        <sources>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel" switchValue="Information,ActivityTracing"
            propagateActivity="true">
            <listeners>
              <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
          </source>
          <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
            <listeners>
              <add name="xml" />
            </listeners>
          </source>
        </sources>
        <sharedListeners>
          <add initializeData="C:\logs\TracingAndLogging-service.svclog" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
            name="xml" />
        </sharedListeners>
        <trace autoflush="true" />
    </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>
                <diagnostics>
                <messageLogging
      logMessagesAtTransportLevel="true"
      logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
      logMalformedMessages="true"
      logEntireMessage="true"
      maxSizeOfMessageToLog="65535000"
      maxMessagesToLog="500" />
                </diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 0):

maxMessagesToLog set to 500.
Try changing that to 5000.

Pain that their isn't rolling logging built in.